# Azure DevOps Artifacts 401 error when publishing npm extension

Tags: npm, azure-devops

I'm trying to get Azure DevOps Artifacts service up and running. I can get it to work with the 90-day token generated by DevOps but not with a custom PAT generated by my account Security panel. It just gives me a 401 error. I followed the instructions for the PAT from here: [PAT instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/get-started-npm?view=vsts&tabs=new-nav%2Cmac)

My registry url is https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/mycompany/_packaging/packages/npm/registry/

My extension .npmrc file is like this:

```
registry=https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/mycompany/_packaging/packages/npm/registry/
always-auth=true
```

My system .npmrc is like this:

```
//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
//pkgs.dev.azure.com/mycompany/_packaging/packages/npm/registry/:username=mycompany
//pkgs.dev.azure.com/mycompany/_packaging/packages/npm/registry/:_password=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
//pkgs.dev.azure.com/mycompany/_packaging/packages/npm/registry/:email=devservices@mycompany.ca
//pkgs.dev.azure.com/mycompany/_packaging/packages/npm/registry/:always-auth=true
```

If it helps, here's the settings I used to generate the PAT:

[image: DevOps PAT settings]

Any guesses where I might be going wrong?

Comment: Open the Artifacts > Feed > Feed Settings (Cog) > Permissions . Are you a contributor or owner for the feed you are trying to upload to?

Comment: For future reference, you should redact things like auth tokens when posting logs to public sites. You redacted your account name, but your profile shows your employer and that's all a determined attacker needs.

Comment: @DanielMann I totally agree. I left it in because there was a previous issue reported where the instructions were Base64 encoding the token incorrectly. I wanted to show that it was the correct format. Don't worry though, I'd already revoked the token before posting.

Comment: @michaeldejulia Yes, I'm the owner for the feed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Any guesses where I might be going wrong?

Please have a try to generate a PAT with a narrow scope of **"Packaging (read and write)**, not **build** permission. You could click the [show all scopes] to find it.

For more information, please refer to [set up your npmrc files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/get-started-npm?view=vsts&tabs=new-nav%2Cwindows#step-3-set-up-your-npmrc-files)

[image]

[image]